# CMake adds an invalid option when compiling asm

Tags: assembly, gcc, cmake

In the context of builing an OS, I'm switching from Makefile to CMake. With Makefile, I was able to control every character that was going to be executed in the command line, and CMake doesn't allow me to do this, and adds faulty options to the command.

With this code

```
file(
    GLOB_RECURSE KERNEL_ASM_SOURCES
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.s
)

# CMAKE_ASM_FLAGS left empty

add_executable(
    os.bin
    ${KERNEL_CPP_SOURCES}
    ${KERNEL_ASM_SOURCES}
)
```

The output command is

```
[1/5] Building ASM object kernel/CMakeFiles/os.bin.dir/src/boot.s.obj
FAILED: kernel/CMakeFiles/os.bin.dir/src/boot.s.obj 
/usr/local/cross/bin/i686-elf-as  -I../../kernel/include -I../../kernel/../stl/include -MM -g -MD -MT kernel/CMakeFiles/os.bin.dir/src/boot.s.obj -MF kernel/CMakeFiles/os.bin.dir/src/boot.s.obj.d -o kernel/CMakeFiles/os.bin.dir/src/boot.s.obj -c ../../kernel/src/boot.s
/usr/local/cross/bin/i686-elf-as: invalid option -- 'F'
```

(i686-elf-as is the gcc assembler)
I guess the F refers to the -MF option, which is a valid gcc parameter, but I don't understand why it is here, and why it is invalid.

`i686-elf-as -v` output is `GNU assembler version 2.39 (i686-elf) using BFD version (GNU Binutils) 2.39`

Here is the toolchain I use :

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR i686)

set(CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING 1)

set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE "STATIC_LIBRARY")

set(BINUTILS_PATH /usr/local/cross/bin)
set(TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX i686-elf-)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${BINUTILS_PATH}/${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}gcc)
set(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER ${BINUTILS_PATH}/${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}as)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${BINUTILS_PATH}/${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}g++)

set(CRTI ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/kernel/src/crti.s)
set(CRTN ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/kernel/src/crtn.s)
execute_process(
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} ${CXXFLAGS} ${LDFLAGS} -print-file-name=crtbegin.o
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE CRTBEGIN
    OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
)
execute_process(
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} ${CXXFLAGS} ${LDFLAGS} -print-file-name=crtend.o
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE CRTEND
    OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
)

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOTPATH /usr/local/cross/lib/gcc/i686-elf/12.2.0)

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)
```

I would like the compile command to be as simple `i686-elf-as input.s -o input.s.obj`, is there a way to execute this command myself, or any kind of known workaround for this problem?

Comment: Looks like it wants to assemble using gcc hence the options. Maybe you have overridden `gcc` to `as` somewhere?

Comment: I don't think so. I'm updating the question with the toolchain I'm using.

Comment: Normally you'd want the output filename to be `input.o` for `input.s`.  You're using an ELF assembler, and the convention is `.o` not `.obj` for ELF objects.  Also, the `.o` suffix normally replaces `.s`, not appends.

Comment: It is what I want, and my question is why it is doing something else by default.